# Push view to navigation controller from button in other class

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton, pushviewcontroller

I have a UIButton that I create in my sub class ViewController, and add it to my MainViewController.

Now, I added a target method to this button that should push another view controller to my Navigation controller (the one that in the MainViewController).

I know that the method did call when I push the button, but the view wasn't push to the Navigation Controller.

I scanned this drawing - this is the drawing (I also added part of my code):

[image: question Drawing]

This is the code I'm using in my button:
**(remember it's in a deferent ViewController).**

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    Photo_ScreenGlobalView *photo = [[Photo_ScreenGlobalView alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:photo animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Please check the View outlet set to your controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually I solve these situations with delegation. If there is a view controller which is subordinate to another (i.e. a "sub" view controller) but should have the ability to trigger navigation changes, etc... then it should have a weak pointer back to it's 'parent'. Then the parent VC should implement an appropriately named protocol with a callback for the child to use. The names of these things can be generic, such as `@property navigationDelegate` and `requestNavigationToViewController:` or they can be more semantic, such as `@property userFormDelegate` and `userFormDoneButtonPressed:`

Generally speaking, a subordinate view controller should not be able to directly modify navigation at it's parent's level; but it can trigger it via more loosely-coupoled interfaces like these.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - but can you please let me see how to do it with code example ? i didn't understand it to the end..

Comment: if someone need it -You can see a guide in the answer below.

Answer (score -3):

i came back to let you all know how i actually did it.
after googling a lot found this nice and quick guide how to make **DELEGATE**
and working with delegate solved all my problems. if you need any help don't hesitate to send me PM.

this is the guide:
http://css.dzone.com/articles/do-not-publishcreating-your

Comment: This is my posted solution from 7 days ago.

Comment: well, thank you. but it wasn't so clear and this guide explain it real better.